# Android - Broadcast Intent original copy or clone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Its just tricky question. But I want deep diving in Android.

Please tell me, if my app receive Broadcast Receive with intent.
Received intent(where System or other app sendBroadcast(intent)), 
**Is It original copy of intent or it clone of intent?**